# dotnet core console app on debian - see output on screen?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, .net-core, debian

I'm making the transition from windows to linux with dotnet core 3.1 console apps but not seeing the console app output on terminal window

i've installed the dotnet core runtime on debian

I built the solution using

```
dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained --runtime debian-x64
```

Then I used winSCP to copy the files to the usr/local/release folder

in the terminal i browse to folder and run using ./myappname

the terminal window seems like its doing something, but i see no output, if i ctrl z, it then prints 'stopped'

Should i be seeing the console app output on terminal screen? if not, what command do i use to see the console.writeline output?

The app should first print name of running app, then every 1 min print out stats to screen (this is what is does on windows)

this is quite a basic app but unfortunately does not log to file.

Answer (score 0):

so it turned out someone had used

```
Console.Title = "blah";
```

at top, that doesn't work on linux, but the I got no errors when publishing as linux to tell me its not supported

Comment: this seems to be fixed in the net core 6, and probably earlier versions. but 3.1 had issues with console.title